# Bootstrap | I can't get a background image in my site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background, background-image

I've tried everything what I could find in previous answers, but without any succes. I can change the background**color** bot not the background**image**. So what do I have to add excactly to the code, to succesfully insert a full screen background? Hope somebody can help me!

Here's my html: (I'll paste the whole document so you can see all)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Minecraft How To | Article</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/pagestyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <a href="#">Minecraft know how</a>
                </div>
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Making a server <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Tips and Tricks</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">other</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class="col-md-2" id="leftCol">
                    <ul class="nav nav-stacked affix affix-top" id="sidebar">
                    <li><a href="#part0">Welcome to the Article</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#part1">Heading 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#part2">Heading 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#part3">Last heading</a></li>
                    </ul>


                </div>

                        <div class = "col-md-8">

                            <div class = "panel panel-default">

                                <div class = "panel-body">

                                        <h3 id="part0" class = "page-header">Welcome to the Article</h3>

                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet varius ligula vel interdum. Donec ut sapien nec eros pellentesque viverra vitae quis sem. Cras odio lorem, commodo mollis consequat nec, tempor vel sapien. Integer odio magna, luctus nec laoreet ut, rutrum vitae diam. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor in lectus accumsan, sed congue mi facilisis. Sed mi arcu, egestas vel turpis sed, feugiat laoreet nibh. Duis sit amet tincidunt urna. Nunc elementum elementum mauris quis feugiat. Phasellus pretium nunc sed ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Vestibulum nec tortor sed ligula ornare lacinia. Nullam a turpis magna. Vivamus at interdum erat. Vestibulum bibendum lorem in feugiat ultricies. Fusce consequat eu risus sit amet vehicula. Maecenas auctor odio ipsum. Phasellus convallis est eu cursus lacinia.</p>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet varius ligula vel interdum. Donec ut sapien nec eros pellentesque viverra vitae quis sem. Cras odio lorem, commodo mollis consequat nec, tempor vel sapien. Integer odio magna, luctus nec laoreet ut, rutrum vitae diam. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor in lectus accumsan, sed congue mi facilisis. Sed mi arcu, egestas vel turpis sed, feugiat laoreet nibh. Duis sit amet tincidunt urna. Nunc elementum elementum mauris quis feugiat. Phasellus pretium nunc sed ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Vestibulum nec tortor sed ligula ornare lacinia. Nullam a turpis magna. Vivamus at interdum erat. Vestibulum bibendum lorem in feugiat ultricies. Fusce consequat eu risus sit amet vehicula. Maecenas auctor odio ipsum. Phasellus convallis est eu cursus lacinia.</p>

                                    <h4 id="part1">Heading 1</h4>

                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet varius ligula vel interdum. Donec ut sapien nec eros pellentesque viverra vitae quis sem. Cras odio lorem, commodo mollis consequat nec, tempor vel sapien. Integer odio magna, luctus nec laoreet ut, rutrum vitae diam. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor in lectus accumsan, sed congue mi facilisis. Sed mi arcu, egestas vel turpis sed, feugiat laoreet nibh. Duis sit amet tincidunt urna. Nunc elementum elementum mauris quis feugiat. Phasellus pretium nunc sed ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Vestibulum nec tortor sed ligula ornare lacinia. Nullam a turpis magna. Vivamus at interdum erat. Vestibulum bibendum lorem in feugiat ultricies. Fusce consequat eu risus sit amet vehicula. Maecenas auctor odio ipsum. Phasellus convallis est eu cursus lacinia.</p>

                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet varius ligula vel interdum. Donec ut sapien nec eros pellentesque viverra vitae quis sem. Cras odio lorem, commodo mollis consequat nec, tempor vel sapien. Integer odio magna, luctus nec laoreet ut, rutrum vitae diam. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor in lectus accumsan, sed congue mi facilisis. Sed mi arcu, egestas vel turpis sed, feugiat laoreet nibh. Duis sit amet tincidunt urna. Nunc elementum elementum mauris quis feugiat. Phasellus pretium nunc sed ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Vestibulum nec tortor sed ligula ornare lacinia. Nullam a turpis magna. Vivamus at interdum erat. Vestibulum bibendum lorem in feugiat ultricies. Fusce consequat eu risus sit amet vehicula. Maecenas auctor odio ipsum. Phasellus convallis est eu cursus lacinia.</p>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet varius ligula vel interdum. Donec ut sapien nec eros pellentesque viverra vitae quis sem. Cras odio lorem, commodo mollis consequat nec, tempor vel sapien. Integer odio magna, luctus nec laoreet ut, rutrum vitae diam. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor in lectus accumsan, sed congue mi facilisis. Sed mi arcu, egestas vel turpis sed, feugiat laoreet nibh. Duis sit amet tincidunt urna. Nunc elementum elementum mauris quis feugiat. Phasellus pretium nunc sed ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Vestibulum nec tortor sed ligula ornare lacinia. Nullam a turpis magna. Vivamus at interdum erat. Vestibulum bibendum lorem in feugiat ultricies. Fusce consequat eu risus sit amet vehicula. Maecenas auctor odio ipsum. Phasellus convallis est eu cursus lacinia.</p>
                                    <h4 id="part2">Heading 2</h4>

                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet varius ligula vel interdum. Donec ut sapien nec eros pellentesque viverra vitae quis sem. Cras odio lorem, commodo mollis consequat nec, tempor vel sapien. Integer odio magna, luctus nec laoreet ut, rutrum vitae diam. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor in lectus accumsan, sed congue mi facilisis. Sed mi arcu, egestas vel turpis sed, feugiat laoreet nibh. Duis sit amet tincidunt urna. Nunc elementum elementum mauris quis feugiat. Phasellus pretium nunc sed ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Vestibulum nec tortor sed ligula ornare lacinia. Nullam a turpis magna. Vivamus at interdum erat. Vestibulum bibendum lorem in feugiat ultricies. Fusce consequat eu risus sit amet vehicula. Maecenas auctor odio ipsum. Phasellus convallis est eu cursus lacinia.</p>                       
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet varius ligula vel interdum. Donec ut sapien nec eros pellentesque viverra vitae quis sem. Cras odio lorem, commodo mollis consequat nec, tempor vel sapien. Integer odio magna, luctus nec laoreet ut, rutrum vitae diam. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor in lectus accumsan, sed congue mi facilisis. Sed mi arcu, egestas vel turpis sed, feugiat laoreet nibh. Duis sit amet tincidunt urna. Nunc elementum elementum mauris quis feugiat. Phasellus pretium nunc sed ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Vestibulum nec tortor sed ligula ornare lacinia. Nullam a turpis magna. Vivamus at interdum erat. Vestibulum bibendum lorem in feugiat ultricies. Fusce consequat eu risus sit amet vehicula. Maecenas auctor odio ipsum. Phasellus convallis est eu cursus lacinia.</p>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet varius ligula vel interdum. Donec ut sapien nec eros pellentesque viverra vitae quis sem. Cras odio lorem, commodo mollis consequat nec, tempor vel sapien. Integer odio magna, luctus nec laoreet ut, rutrum vitae diam. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor in lectus accumsan, sed congue mi facilisis. Sed mi arcu, egestas vel turpis sed, feugiat laoreet nibh. Duis sit amet tincidunt urna. Nunc elementum elementum mauris quis feugiat. Phasellus pretium nunc sed ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Vestibulum nec tortor sed ligula ornare lacinia. Nullam a turpis magna. Vivamus at interdum erat. Vestibulum bibendum lorem in feugiat ultricies. Fusce consequat eu risus sit amet vehicula. Maecenas auctor odio ipsum. Phasellus convallis est eu cursus lacinia.</p>

                                    <h4 id="part3">Heading 3</h4>

                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet varius ligula vel interdum. Donec ut sapien nec eros pellentesque viverra vitae quis sem. Cras odio lorem, commodo mollis consequat nec, tempor vel sapien. Integer odio magna, luctus nec laoreet ut, rutrum vitae diam. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor in lectus accumsan, sed congue mi facilisis. Sed mi arcu, egestas vel turpis sed, feugiat laoreet nibh. Duis sit amet tincidunt urna. Nunc elementum elementum mauris quis feugiat. Phasellus pretium nunc sed ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Vestibulum nec tortor sed ligula ornare lacinia. Nullam a turpis magna. Vivamus at interdum erat. Vestibulum bibendum lorem in feugiat ultricies. Fusce consequat eu risus sit amet vehicula. Maecenas auctor odio ipsum. Phasellus convallis est eu cursus lacinia.</p>                                                            
                                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet varius ligula vel interdum. Donec ut sapien nec eros pellentesque viverra vitae quis sem. Cras odio lorem, commodo mollis consequat nec, tempor vel sapien. Integer odio magna, luctus nec laoreet ut, rutrum vitae diam. Vivamus ullamcorper tortor in lectus accumsan, sed congue mi facilisis. Sed mi arcu, egestas vel turpis sed, feugiat laoreet nibh. Duis sit amet tincidunt urna. Nunc elementum elementum mauris quis feugiat. Phasellus pretium nunc sed ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Vestibulum nec tortor sed ligula ornare lacinia. Nullam a turpis magna. Vivamus at interdum erat. Vestibulum bibendum lorem in feugiat ultricies. Fusce consequat eu risus sit amet vehicula. Maecenas auctor odio ipsum. Phasellus convallis est eu cursus lacinia.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <p class=page-footer>By Job Verberne | This page was last modified on 23 Februari 2014<p>
                        </div>
            <div class = "col-md-2">
                <div class = "list-group affix">
                    <a href = "#" class = "list-group-item">
                        <h4 class = "list-group-item-heading">Related Article</h4>
                        <p class = "list-group-item-text">This is a short preview of the text what's in this article. Click here to read more...</p>
                    </a>
                    <a href = "#" class = "list-group-item">
                        <h4 class = "list-group-item-heading">Related Article</h4>
                        <p class = "list-group-item-text">This is a short preview of the text what's in this article. Click here to read more...</p>
                    </a>
                    <a href = "#" class = "list-group-item">
                        <h4 class = "list-group-item-heading">Related Article</h4>
                        <p class = "list-group-item-text">This is a short preview of the text what's in this article. Click here to read more...</p>
                    </a>
                    <a href = "#" class = "list-group-item">
                        <h4 class = "list-group-item-heading">Related Article</h4>
                        <p class = "list-group-item-text">This is a short preview of the text what's in this article. Click here to read more...</p>
                    </a>
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



        <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-bottom">

            <div class = "container">
                    <p class = "navbar-text pull-left">Copyright Minecraft How To. All rights reserved</p>
                    <a href = "#" class = "navbar-btn btn-default btn pull-right">Subscribe on YouTube</a>
            </div>

        </div>        


            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script>$('#sidebar')
            var $body   = $(document.body);
            var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 10;

            $body.scrollspy({
                target: '#leftCol',
                offset: navHeight
            });

            /* smooth scrolling sections */
            $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                  var target = $(this.hash);
                  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                  if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                      scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80
                    }, 800);
                    return false;
                  }
                }
            });
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my css file:

```
body {

  padding-top: 90px;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.navbar-static-bottom {
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.nav > li > a {
  color: #a5a5a5;
}

#sidebar > li > a {
  padding: 6px;
}

#sidebar > li > a:hover, #sidebar > li > a:focus{ 
  background-color: transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid #0b9411;
  color: #0b9411;
}

#sidebar .affix-top {
  position: static;
  margin-top:30px;
   width:228px;
  color: #0b9411;
}

#sidebar .affix {
  position: fixed;
  width:228px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#sidebar li.active > a {
  border: 0 #0b9411 solid;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  color: #0b9411;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#leftCol {
  max-width: 12%;
}

.list-group {
  max-width: 14%;
}

.page-footer {
  margin: -15px 2px 50px 0px;
  color: #0b9411 ;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a **full-screen** (responsive) background image  you will want to use this snippet of css in your project.  In this example I set the style for the "body" tag but this technique could be used for any element within you webpage.

```
   body { background: url(http://www.pulserealestateonline.com/todd.jpg) 
   no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;"

  }
```

Here's a working demo on [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mFc8D/1/)